# What is idc short for in H.264?

Tags: c++, decode, encode, h.264

For exmaple, `nal_ref_idc` and `profile_idc`. I knew what they are, but I can not find the `idc`'s full name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> profile_idc -> Profile identification for the Encoder

refer https://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/sprufd

I think IDC mean "identification" for the Encoder ,
this question may not programming relevant one

Comment: It's relevant to understand the data structure of H.264.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "Indication".
coz "id" is a better choice than "idc" for "identification"

Ref:

7.4.2.1 Sequence parameter set RBSP semantics profile_idc and level_idc indicate the profile and level to which the bitstream conforms, as specified in Annex A.